# Writing numbers in arabic in lualatex

Tags: luatex, arabic

For the shown MWE, I am using Lualatex to prepare a document with "Arabic" set as the default language. Upon trying to write numbers as well as fractions inline with text, they appear in English and not arabic. Notice that upon avoiding the use of "\num{..}", the number are arranged randomly within text in certain scenarios, hence the need to use the command "\num{...}".

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

%Babel package settings
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}


% Fonts%
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{mathpazo}


%MAths Environment%
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition} 



% Numbers and units%

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,inter-unit-product = \cdot, exponent-product = \ast, output-product = \ast, group-separator = \text{~}, group-minimum-digits={3}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{smartunits}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{rccol}
\usepackage{warpcol}
\usepackage{fltpoint}

%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================
\begin{document}

\num{1}
\newline
$\frac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation output]

Comment: you need `\num[mode=text]{1}` or detect-mode if you want num to use text numbers.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, do you have additional clues with regard to the fractions?

Comment: The numbers we use in English are called arabic numbers. What kind of 'arabic numbers' are you after?

Comment: And there is no random arrangements. Because you use arabic, the text is RTL, so you start at the right of the page. The first line of a paragraph has indent by default, so therefore it is not entirely to the right of the page. The next line has no indent, it is right at the margin.

Comment: @Vincent, I mean writing numbers in Arabic language (I believe they are called Hindi, I am not sure) and not English language, Numbers written in a format similar to that by which the page number on the upper LHS of the page is written. Also, by arrangement I mean that when written among text sometimes they become inappropriately arranged.

Comment: @Silva I don't know if LuaLaTeX supports the features of XeLaTeX, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172619/242407 would be a good place to start investigating